# How to return from nested deferred then() function

Tags: javascript

I need to make many API calls with different settings, so I'm trying to write a function that will take a settings object and return text.  I had this working before function-izing it, but now I can't figure out how to get the data out.  The `data` variable is good here, but how can I pass it back to `answer`?  I tried adding a `this` reference, this is my current attempt.

```
 function REST(settings) {
    var whatIneed;
    var parent = this;
    client.request(settings).then(
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            parent.whatIneed = data;
        },
        function(response) { PromiseError(response); } )
    console.log(whatIneed);
    return whatIneed;
}

answer = REST(settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using an asynchronous call that returns a promise in a synchronous manner. When you return `whatIneed` at the end of `REST` its value will still be `undefined` because the `then` block from the `client` call has not executed yet.

If you are using a transpiler you could use `await` to await the data before returning it or you could return the promise directly from `REST` and then use it like `REST(settings).then(function(data) { // do something})`

Comment: I've just read the linked super-thread on the topic and now I understand the problem. I did have it working before by returning the promise directly like you said, but I was trying to avoid having lots of nested callbacks. I will look into `await`, thanks.